# AWS Step Function: The JSONPath '$.S3_BUCKET' specified for the field 'Value.$' could not be found

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

Starting Step function with the following input

```
[{\"name\":\"S3_BUCKET\",\"value\":\"test-bucket\"},{\"name\":\"S3_KEY\",\"value\":\"key-name.txt\"}]'"
```

What is the correct way to pass this to ECS's container? here is what I have so far under the step functions parameters

```
      "Overrides": {
            "ContainerOverrides": [
                {
                  "Name": "test",
                  "Environment": [
                  { "Name": "S3_BUCKET", "Value.$": "$.S3_BUCKET"}
                   ]
                }
              ]
           }
      },
```

Here is the error message I am getting:

> The JSONPath '$.S3_BUCKET' specified for the field 'Value.$' could not be found

Comment: Is your current configuration not working?

Comment: i am not able to get the right information passed along 
i believe i need to fix this part ""Value.$": "$.S3_BUCKET"" my error is the following The JSONPath '$.S3_BUCKET' specified for the field 'Value.$' could not be found in

Comment: Why did you not include the error message in your initial question?

Comment: it's an obvious error in the code and not written correctly. Was hoping someone can provide better guidance on how to properly fetch the information

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help someone else, took me some time to figure this out

If you are launching Step Function via cloudwatch and want to pass in some environment variables to ECS/Fargate. I ended up using constant instead of input_transformer

here is the terraform code for aws_cloudwatch_event_target

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "cloudwatch-ecs-target" {
 arn    = aws_sfn_state_machine.YOUR-STATEMACHINE.arn
 rule     = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.CLOUDWATCH_RULE.name
 role_arn = aws_iam_role.YOUR-ROLE.arn
     input = <<JSON
{
   "ENV1": "ABC",
   "ENV2": "XYZ",
}
JSON
}
```

Here is how state machine terraform code looks like

```
resource "aws_sfn_state_machine" "STATEMACHINE" {
  name     = "STATEMACHINE-NAME"
  role_arn = aws_iam_role.YOUR-ROLE.arn

  definition = <<EOF
  {
  "StartAt": "Run Fargate Task",
  "States": {
    "Run Fargate Task": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "LaunchType": "FARGATE",
        "Cluster": "${aws_ecs_cluster.YOUR-ECS-CLUSTER.arn}",
        "TaskDefinition": "${local.task_definition_arn_only}",
        "NetworkConfiguration": {
          "AwsvpcConfiguration": {
            "Subnets": [
             "${aws_subnet.subnet-a.id}", "${aws_subnet.subnet-b.id}", "${aws_subnet.subnet-c.id}"
             ],
            "AssignPublicIp": "ENABLED"
          }
        },
      "Overrides": {
            "ContainerOverrides": [
                {
                  "Name": "ECS-CLUSTER-NAME",
                  "Environment": [
                  { "Name": "ENV1", "Value.$": "$.ENV1"},
                  { "Name": "ENV2", "Value.$": "$.ENV2"},
                   ]
                }
              ]
           }
      },
        "End": true
     }
  }
}
  EOF
}
```